# Good collar tracker for my deaf cat

Tags: cats, safety, containment, outdoor, lost-pet

I have a deaf cat, 7 years old, and I've been trying to find a tracker for her collar but there's so many different options I don't know which type is best.
As she's deaf she's an indoor cat and so there's always the fear she'll get out and be lost (and since she's never been outside it would be very dangerous for her). There is also the issue that she's on occasion found a new hiding place to wriggle into thus causing a housewide search and not knowing if she's somehow gotten out (and being deaf shaking a box of treats doesn't help!).
Having a tracker would take a lot of the worry out especially as there have been a lot of missing cats in our area recently.
But there's so many different kinds of tracker (gps, radio, bluetooth) and they all have their pros and cons so any reccomendations would be really appreciated!

Note: she's a rescue which is why we're only now looking at trackers

Comment: I don't know much about tracking devices, but I would start by looking at ones specifically designed for tracking pets.  I believe you should be looking at GPS trackers rather than bluetooth.  Bluetooth is a technology standard for exchanging data short distance over radio.  I would not expect trackers using bluetooth to be useful for the case the cat escapes outside.  But that's sort of the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Bluetooth trackers can still be useful for this sort of thing. One can tell you whether (and where) your pet is still in the house so you can know whether an outdoor search is needed. If you do need to search outside, you can use it for proximity detection which might speed up your search instead of having to look under and behind everything. Not as good at actual tracking (assuming your GPS unit can acquire satellites and a cell tower) but smaller and lighter, better battery life, probably cheaper.

Comment: Airtags from Apple can be used to track pets as well. If you are from the US and Europe, the ubiquity of iPhones makes Airtags more usable for long distance tracking than bluetooth ones. GPS ones are great but they have a very limited ON-time.